# Rails Drive Rest Api | Sharing file using google api client gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api

I'm building an application who implements some drive functions. Now I'm trying to share a file using the google-api-ruby-client gem. I have some troubles using the next code.

```
#Here, I create a DriveService object and I authorize it.
#This works fine. In my app I list drive files well.
@drive = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
@drive.authorization = @token[:access_token]

#Here, first I create a permission object with some parameters
#Then I call create_permission to share the file to a other user
per=Google::Apis::DriveV3::Permission.new(type: "user", role: "writer",email_address: "some@gmail.com")
@drive.create_permission(file_id:"0B8XBWuVEmvN8YS01OXNUcHhOYWs",permission_object: per, fields: "id", &callback)
```

When I execute this code, the callback show this:

```
{
"error": {
 "errors": [
  {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "The permission type field is required.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "permission.type"
  }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The permission type field is required."
 }
```

}

I can't solve this error. Can someone help me?

Comment: The debugger points to the @drive.create_permission line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I pass a permission object like the documentation says, doesn't works, so the correct form, and the only who works for me is:

```
user_permission = {type: "user", role: "writer", email_address: "some@gmail.com"}
@drive.create_permission(current_user.fileId, user_permission, send_notification_email: false, fields: 'id', &callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the debugger points to the @drive.create_permission line, it means it's looking for 'type' permission in that line. Try adding your field values

```
type: "user", role: "writer"
```

to that line so it will look like this:

```
@drive.create_permission(file_id:"0B8XBWuVEmvN8YS01OXNUcHhOYWs",type: "user", role: "writer", permission_object: per, fields: "id", &callback)
```

Comment: Doesn't works, I think the error its related with the object "per". http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/DriveV3/DriveService. Here you can see the documentation

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone is using the google javascript library, the field name on the permission create for the permission structure is 'resource'